# How can I debug "Errors occurred during the build" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I get "Building workspace has encountered a problem. Errors occurred during the build." in Eclipse is there a way to debug this?

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> then type Error Log. It should show what's going on.

Edit: If you want to debug Eclipse's problems, I guess you have to start it in debug mode. Never tried it myself, but see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2332050/116509

Comment: Yes, I know about Error Log and can see the exception there. Should have clarified: I meant running build under a debugger so I can see why I get the exception :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the API level in project properties-> android, and restart the eclipse, and again change the API level to the previous one.

This worked for me..