# Learn to manipulate the buttons of Eclipse's debugging mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging

This post is *not* a duplicate of

[Debug eclipse IDE itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324852/debug-eclipse-ide)

neither of this one

[Debug eclipse IDE itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324852/debug-eclipse-ide)

The background is, I almost know nothing about debugging  whinin Eclipse. I have been using 'print' and 'assert' since years for debugging.

Where can I learn how to manipulate the 36 buttons of the debugging mode in Eclipse?? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The above `Debug eclipse IDE` links are the same. Perhaps the second link should point to a different post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of links you could use.

For instance :

**[Debugging with Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=503)** ( The official tutorial)

as well as this,

**[Java Debugging with Eclipse - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html)**