# Error during build in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, export

An error dialog as in the picture is popping up while exporting an android application.

Tell me how to solve this error.

[image: error dialog in eclipse]

Answer (score 1):

Pramod,

I assume it means there are errors in your source code.

Back in Eclipse, trying cleaning (under Project - Clean - Clean all projects.

Also checkout this post 
[Debug eclipse IDE itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324852/debug-eclipse-ide/2332050#2332050)